# searchd.development.pid.lock permission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx

Whenever I try to run my app on my local machine, I get this, and of course, it's not working. There is no searchd.development.pid file in the log directory.

```
MB:my_app victor$ ./script/server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.8 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
** Erubis 2.6.6
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/daemon_controller-0.2.5/lib/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:63:in `initialize': Permission denied - /Users/victorng/Documents/Projects/my_app/Development/my_app/log/searchd.development.pid.lock (Errno::EACCES)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/daemon_controller-0.2.5/lib/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:63:in `open'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/daemon_controller-0.2.5/lib/daemon_controller/lock_file.rb:63:in `exclusive_lock'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/daemon_controller-0.2.5/lib/daemon_controller.rb:197:in `start'
    from /Users/victorng/Documents/Projects/my_app/Development/my_app/config/initializers/daemon_thinking_sphinx.rb:23
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load_without_new_constant_marking'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:145:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
    from /Users/victorng/Documents/Projects/my_app/Development/my_app/config/environment.rb:9
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from ./script/server:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your user has no acces to this directory to write the lock file Change the right in this directory to allow you to write inside.